# Creating loading messages with swfobject

Tags: flash, swfobject

I am loading a flash file via swfobject. As the file is large, I want to show a "please wait while loading" message while the flash is loading.

How can I do it with swfobject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a small preloader SWF that triggers a loading-please-wait animation and then loads the real SWF in the background. There are lots of free preloaders on the web.

Comment: We have a animated GIF which we use as preloader is it possible to use that instead of using another flash preloader.